# Problem uploading a file - probably has something to do with passing segments in url

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

The code below keeps putting images in the folder `assets/images/photoAlbums`, but i feel like it should be putting them in the folder `assets/images/photoAlbums/$album`.

When I first load up the page, it displays the url with `controller/addPhoto/Testing`, and the addPhoto view just has a form where a user chooses a file and clicks submit. It submits it to this same controller function addPhoto, only when you submit the page, it doesn't have the `Testing` segment in the URL anymore and that is the reason it keeps uploading to `assets/images/photoAlbums`.

I think all I need to do is pass the segment when I load the view again, but I can't figure out how to pass a segment when I load the view.

```
/**
    * addPhoto - function which shows the add photo page
    */
    function addPhoto()
    {   
        $album = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/photoAlbums/'.$album.'/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|pjpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';   // that's 2MBs
        $config['max_width'] = '1200';
        $config['max_height'] = '1200';
        $config['remove_space'] = TRUE;
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

        echo "album = ".$album;
        echo "config = ".$config['upload_path'];

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userFile')) { // if there are errors...
            //echo "fail";
            $content_data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $content_data['data'] = array('upload_data'=>$this->upload->data());
            $content_data['title'] = ' | Rochester Water Ski Show Team';
            $content_data['firstName'] = $this->session->userdata('firstName');
            $data['sess'] = $this->session;
            $data['content'] = $this->load->view('member/addPhoto', $content_data, true);
            $this->load->view('template/admin', $data);

        } else {    // else there are NO errors
            //echo "success";
            $content_data['data'] = array('upload_data'=>$this->upload->data());
            $content_data['title'] = ' | Rochester Water Ski Show Team';
            $content_data['firstName'] = $this->session->userdata('firstName');
            $data['sess'] = $this->session;
            $data['content'] = $this->load->view('member/addPhoto_success', $content_data, true);
            $this->load->view('template/admin', $data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to retrieve the segment with $this->uri->segment(3).

If you call your controller as you do, `controller/addPhoto/Testing`, you can retrive the parameter automatically in your method:

```
function addPhoto($album) {
    echo $album;   // output: 'Testing';
}
```

$album is now already available inside your method.

If your parameter is somewhat static, you can use the form method to pass said paramenter, like `echo form_open('controller/addPhoto/albumname');`.

If you want it dynamic, then you can twist a bit the logic and pass the name using an hidden field, in this way your method will be called without parameters  `echo form_open('controller/addPhoto')`, and you retrieve the album name through `$this->input->post('myhiddeninput')`.

If you feel I misunderstood something just let know.

Comment: That was simple. Thanks for your help.